# Upload multipart form with request and form-data

Tags: node.js, forms, request

I am submitting an image to an API.

When I go into postman, I can submit to API and it works fine:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://myURL.com \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'stringPart=string' \
  -F myfile.jpg=@/path/to/file/myfile.jpg
```

My code looks like this:

```
const request = require("request");
require('request-to-curl');
const fs = require("fs");
var FormData = require('form-data');

let url = 'https://myURL.com';
let headers = {
    'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
};
const formData = {
    // Pass a simple key-value pair
    stringPart: 'string',
    'myfile.jpg': fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/myfile.jpg'),
};
request.post({url:url, headers: headers, formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
    console.log(httpResponse.request.req.toCurl());
    if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
    }
    console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

This gets an error from the server.
The curl statement outputted looks like this, I have cut off the image because it goes on for pages.

```
curl 'https://myURL.com' \
     -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------798817746202249113209224' \
--data-binary $'----------------------------798817746202249113209224\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="stringPart"\r\n\r\nstring\r\n----------------------------798817746202249113209224\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="myfile.jpg"; filename="myfile.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00H\x00H\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\x00XExif\x00\x00MM\x00*\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x02\x01\x12\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\ufffdi\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\ufffd\x01\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\ufffd\x02\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\ufffd\x03\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\x008Photoshop 3.0\x008BIM\x04\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x008BIM\x04%
```

... goes on for a while.

How can I get my code to match the curl statement that works?
Thanks.

Comment: What error message do you get from the server?

Comment: You are not authorized to perform the request. I think this is just a generic message.